# Routing And Remote Access with VPN Installed On Same Server

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, openvpn

**Setup**

I have a Windows Server 2022 with Routing and Remote Access (RRAS) installed.

[image]

The server has two (NICs) ethernet ports.

I have the following setup in RRAS.

`Ethernet 1` is the `Switch -> Server` link and `Ethernet 2` is the `Server -> Client` link.

[image]

**Issue**

The client is able to get internet access until the VPN software (OpenVPN / WireGaurd) is enabled on the server.

I am trying to get the client to use the Server's VPN connection.

I do not see any "interfaces" in RRAS for OpenVPN or WireGaurd that I could add.

Any ideas on what items to troubleshoot in order to get the VPN connection to passthrough?

Comment: I believe this is the third time you have asked this question. This is also a question that is asked several times per week and is closed as off-topic for this forum. Is there a particular reason you are persisting with this?

Comment: Why are you connecting the server to a VPN? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @GregAskew Let me know where this question should go.

Comment: @joeqwerty I am trying to get the client to use the Server's VPN connection. The server itself connects to a VPN, and then the downstream clients are having there connection routed through the VPN just the same if the client had the VPN installed.